# QGIS Processing Algorithm - change field value using `changeAttributeValue` or other protocol doesn't save changes

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

In a simple processing script I am trying to use Regex to search and then replace any found values with a new value. It seems to run fine but **doesn't save the changes.**

If I keep `.startEditing()` I get

```
Current thread 0x0000332c (most recent call first):
Windows fatal exception: access violation
Thread 0x0000332c (most recent call first):`
```

**Is it possible to save time by only saving the changes once all the edits have been made?**

The whole code is

```
from qgis import processing
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import QgsProject
import operator,re

@alg(name='searchupdatealg', label='Search and update (alg)',
     group='mgm', group_label='Example scripts')
# 'INPUT' is the recommended name for the main input parameter
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name='INPUT', label='Input vector')
@alg.input(type=alg.FIELD, name='Attrib', label='Attribute',
           parentLayerParameterName='INPUT')
@alg.input(type=alg.STRING, name='RegexS', label='Regex String')
@alg.input(type=alg.EXPRESSION, name='OutputS', label='Output String')
# 'OUTPUT' is the recommended name for the main output parameter
@alg.input(type=alg.VECTOR_LAYER_DEST, name='OUTPUT',
           label='Vector output')
           

def searchupdatealg(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """
    Description of the algorithm.
    (If there is no comment here, you will get an error)
    """
    in_layer = instance.parameterAsSource(parameters, 'INPUT', context)
    regex_s = instance.parameterAsString(parameters,'RegexS', context)
    numfeatures = in_layer.featureCount()
    feats = [f for f in in_layer.getFeatures()]
    attrib_n = instance.parameterAsString(parameters,'Attrib', context)
    out_val = instance.parameterAsExpression(parameters,'OutputS', context)
    for feat in feats:
        in_val = feat[attrib_n]
        if len(re.findall(regex_s, in_val))>0:
            #print (in_val, out_val)
            UpdateRecord(in_layer,feat,attrib_n,in_val,out_val)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}
    return {'NUMBEROFFEATURES': numfeatures, 'String': in_val}
    
def UpdateRecord(in_layer,feat,fieldName,in_val,out_val):
    print(in_layer)
    layerf = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(in_layer.sourceName())[0]
    FieldIndex = feat.fields().indexFromName(fieldName)
    layerf.startEditing() #causes QGIS Access violation
    print(feat.id(),FieldIndex,in_val,out_val)
    layerf.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), FieldIndex, out_val)
    layerf.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the start/commit changes need to be in the main function rather than for each change. So

```
from qgis import processing
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import QgsProject
import operator,re

@alg(name='searchupdatealg', label='Search and update (alg)',
     group='mgm', group_label='Custom Scripts')
# 'INPUT' is the recommended name for the main input parameter
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name='INPUT', label='Input vector')
@alg.input(type=alg.FIELD, name='In_Attrib', label='Attribute to search',
           parentLayerParameterName='INPUT')
@alg.input(type=alg.STRING, name='RegexS', label='Regex String')
@alg.input(type=alg.FIELD, name='Out_Attrib', label='Attribute to change',
           parentLayerParameterName='INPUT')
@alg.input(type=alg.EXPRESSION, name='OutputS', label='Output expression')
# 'OUTPUT' is the recommended name for the main output parameter
@alg.input(type=alg.VECTOR_LAYER_DEST, name='OUTPUT',
           label='Vector output')
           

def searchupdatealg(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """
    Search using Regex and output an expression based value
    """
    in_layer = instance.parameterAsSource(parameters, 'INPUT', context)
    regex_s = instance.parameterAsString(parameters,'RegexS', context)
    numfeatures = in_layer.featureCount()
    feats = [f for f in in_layer.getFeatures()]
    in_attrib = instance.parameterAsString(parameters,'In_Attrib', context)
    out_attrib = instance.parameterAsString(parameters,'Out_Attrib', context)
    out_val = instance.parameterAsExpression(parameters,'OutputS', context)
    layerf = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(in_layer.sourceName())[0]
    i=0
    layerf.startEditing()
    for feat in feats:
        in_val = feat[in_attrib]
        if len(re.findall(regex_s, in_val))>0:
            UpdateRecord(layerf,feat,out_attrib,in_val,out_val)
            i+=1
    layerf.commitChanges()
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}
    return {'NUMBEROFFEATURES': numfeatures, 'Number changed': i}
    
def UpdateRecord(layerf,feat,out_attrib,in_val,out_val):
    out_attrib_index = feat.fields().indexFromName(out_attrib)
    print(feat.id(),out_attrib_index,in_val,str(eval(out_val))) #testing only. Comment out in production
    layerf.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), out_attrib_index, str(eval(out_val)))
```